# Fragment empty when hidden then shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ok, this is odd. I am having a problem with the fragment manager with add and replace. So, instead im just loading all of my fragments, and hiding them (which is only 3 fragments). Well, on one of the fragments, if I dont hide it, it works fine. But, if I hide it, then show it again, its just an empty black space. Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I've run into this issue when I'm not holding a reference to the fragment that is hidden/shown and using findFragmentById(). Paste your code so we can help you.

Comment: I've run on similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228401/adding-a-fragment-with-add-method-doesnt-hide-previous-fragments

Comment: I figured it out, but I dont remember what it was. The new fragment API could use some work I think