# listview and fragments

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

The thing is i'm creating a honeycomb app and i can't switch between fragments . Here's my main code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    A = new FragmentA();
    B = new FragmentB();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(mylistener);
}

public void changeFragment(Fragment f){
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment, f);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}

   public OnItemClickListener mylistener = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        switch(position){
        case 0 : changeFragment(A); 
            break;
        case 1 : changeFragment(B); 
            break;
        }

    }
};
```

I know before i put a "replace" i have to remove but how can i remove the one i'm already in ?
What is telling me in the log :
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first .

Comment: Could you clarify that the fragmentA IS displayed on selecting the first entry in the list? If so what happens when you select the second entry in the list? I didn't quite understand your comment 'how can I remove the one I'm already in?'

Comment: the one where i am now is FragmentA, clicking on "one" will open/re-open the fragmentA, and "two" will open fragmentB, i just want to pass from FragmentA to FragmentB by clicking on items in the list .

Comment: Have a look at the API demos FragmentLayout sample as it does something similar to what you want I believe. Firstly add some protection so when when you click on the same list entry you don't reload the same fragment. Secondly be careful when maintaining references, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250580/fragment-already-added-illegalstateexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the API demos FragmentLayout sample as it does something similar to what you want I believe. There's nothing wrong with calling `replace` to load the first fragment as that sample demonstrates.

Firstly add some protection so when when you click on the same list entry you don't reload the same fragment.

Secondly be careful when maintaining references to fragments, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250580/fragment-already-added-illegalstateexception). You may want to recreate the fragments each time or use `remove` and `add` instead of `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with removing the fragment. The `replace` method removes the existing one.

I guess the problem is accessing the fragment inside the listener. Try creating a new fragment inside the listener itself. Please post the complete code.

Comment: This was my complete code . Do you want me to post FragmentA, FragmentB, and all the XML too ?

Comment: There's no problem with accessing the fragment inside the listener.