# Application getting crashed when screen locked in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, tabactivity

I have created a TabActivity class which contains Activity.

I have crated Fragments and using that Fragment inside the activity.

Everything is working perfect until the screen gets locked.

When the screen gets locked, then the app crashes.

This is the stack trace

```
09-25 15:54:36.306: 
E/AndroidRuntime(21443): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No view found for id 0x7f09003d (...id/linearLayoutSC) for fragment SubCategoryGrid{42bbaf70 #7 id=0x7f09003d subCatList}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

I have tried to print the log in **onDestroy()** and **onDetach()** method. It gets called for all the Fragment in a TabActivity.

I have tried this links but not luck with that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446326/1395259

[IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id for fragment when fast switching ActionBar Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589032/illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment-when-fast-switching)

***Is this the bug??***

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19211

Comment: I am working with Fragment mate. Inside 1 activity I have multiple fragment. If the screen gets locked, then onDetach() and onDestroy() is called for all the Fragments in the tabActivity. Thats why the layout file is also get missed. I want to save that. That is not the solution for my query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is resolved.

I dont know what is the role of this here, but it solved my issue and working perfectly.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

**I have written the above line in the `menifest` file inside `activity`**

Now its working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

my issue solved by adding in manifest: below code:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.android.Take Activity"
            android:exported="true"
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" > </activity>
```