# Got exception: fragment already active

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I have a **fragment**;

```
MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
```

I put **bundle data** to this fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("TEST", "test");
myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then, I **replace** old fragment with this one and **put on backstack**:

```
//replace old fragment
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, myFrag, "MyTag");
//put on backstack
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
//commit & get transaction ID
int transId = fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Later, I **pop backstack** with the above transaction ID(`transId`):

```
//pop the transaction from backstack
fragmentManager.popBackStack(transId,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Later, I set **bundle data** as argument again to my fragment(`myFrag`):

```
//Got Java.lang.IllegalStateException: fragment already active
myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
```

As you see, my above code got exception `Java.lang.IllegalStateException: fragment already active` . **I don't understand why** `myFrag` **is still active though I have popped the transaction of it from backstack.**, anyhow, since I got the exception I thought I have no choice but de-active the fragment, So, I did:

```
Fragment activeFragment = fragMgr.findFragmentByTag("MyTag");
fragmentTransaction.remove(activeFragment);
```

I am not sure if my above code really can **de-active** the fragment, since I didn't find how to de-active an fragment. :(

After that, when I try to set bundle data to my fragment `myFrag` again, I still got the same error:

```
Java.lang.IllegalStateException: fragment already active
```

Seems even I removed the fragment, it is still active...**Why? How to de-active a fragment?**

Comment: Is your fragment a singleton? Show me your newInstance() method if you have one.

Comment: I hope this may help someone. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15263921/541620

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15263921/541620
I hope this may help someone.

Comment: I hope this may help someone.
[here][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15263921/541620

Answer (score 152):

Reading the [setArguments(Bundle args)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) source will help you understand:

```
/**
* Supply the construction arguments for this fragment.  This can only
* be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity; that
* is, you should call it immediately after constructing the fragment.  The
* arguments supplied here will be retained across fragment destroy and
* creation.
*/
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {

    if (mIndex >= 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active");
    }
    mArguments = args;
}
```

You cannot use [setArguments(Bundle args)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) again in your code on the same [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html). What you want to do I guess is either create a **new** [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) and set the arguments again. Or you can use [getArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments%28%29) and then use the `put` method of the bundle to change its values.

Comment: +1 for "you can use getArguments() and then use the put methods of bundle to change it's values."

Comment: Here is very good example with detail explanation as well. http://emuneee.com/blog/2013/01/07/saving-fragment-states/

Comment: `getArguments().putAll(bundle);` will overwrite the whole bundle

Comment: `getArguments().putAll(bundle);` does not Override the whole bundle. I still have my previous key and value after calling this one. In  my case, I've used `getArguments().clear();`  and it cleaned up the Arguments.

Comment: You can not use getArguments().putAll() if you not sets setArguments() previusly because getArguments() returns null.

Comment: Do I have to put setArguments(args); again?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the previous fragment before adding the new one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6266144/969325

Comment: I tried firstly "fragmentTransaction.remove(myFrag)" then "replace(...)" , it does not help. I got the same exception

Comment: nono The PREVIOUS. so whatever is on the stack is removed with remove and then you replace with myfrag.

Comment: `fragmentTransaction.remove(myFrag)` removes the fragment from its `addedFragment` stack but keep its instance in its `activeFragment` stack.

Answer (score 1):

remove() change fragment status to de-actiive. In your case, you just didn't call commit() after remove(..).

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(activeFragment);
```

You would do commit() after remove(), too.

```
fragmentTransaction.remove(activeFragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I was adding the fragment to backstack. And the error was because I didn't call popbackstack(). Using popbackstack helped me

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue on Xamarin.android. Here's what [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) says.

> This can only be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity

Answer (score 0):

Just call public method from fragment

```
if(userFragment==null){
                    userFragment = new UserFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(Constants.EXTRA_CUSTOMER, result);
                    userFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                }else{
                    try {
                        Customer customer = new Customer();
                        customer.parseCustomer(new JSONObject(result));
                        userFragment.updateVeiw(customer);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

First I start with describing why this happens and then I'll come up with the solution I found working... .

This issue happens when Android is *removing* the fragment from the stack but is **not yet** finished with removing. In order to check this, you can use the `isRemoving()` method of the fragment. If `false`, i.e. the fragment is not active, you can go on with setting the arguments using `setArguments(bundle)`. Otherwise, you can't set arguments to an already active fragment and can only override it by addressing the same arguments using `getArguments().putAll(bundle)`.

To summarize,

```
    if (myFrag.isRemoving()) {
        myFrag.getArguments().putAll(bundle);
    } else {
        myFrag.setArguments(bundle);
    }
```

If you want to avoid this, i.e. removing the fragment at once so there is no active fragment, you might want to use `onBackPressed()` in `onBackStackChangedListener()`, which will set the `isRemoving()` to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check whether your layout current one or old one for example

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ```
2. Delete old .gradle file in your project file and rebuild gradle file for project.