# How to clear arguments in Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I have an `AudioPlayerFragment` to which I pass some url with setArguments().

If I have an `url` key in the `getArguments()` of my instance of `AudioPlayerFragment`, I start a service that plays the audio stream. If there was already a stream playing, I stop it and start it again with the new stream.

If there is no arguments, I do nothing.

My problem is that the arguments are kept with the instance, so when I get back to it, `getArguments()` returns the latest arguments set, if no new have been set.

So after reading them, I try to set the arguments to null with

```
setArguments(null);
```

But I get

```
Java.lang.IllegalStateException: fragment already active
```

How can I clear the arguments then?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15084683/1276374

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you are reading `getArguments()` in `onCreate()` method of the fragment. Once the fragment was created, when going back you souldn't pass trough `onCreate()`, so you shouldn't be able to read again the arguments.

If this still does not work, you could make use of a boolean flag and read the arguments only once.

Something like this:

```
if(!argumentsRead){

    // read arguments

    argumentsRead = true;
}
```

Answer (score 39):

Call `this.getArguments().clear();` in **onDestroyView()** method in your fragment.

Comment: or `remove(key)` for a specific one

Comment: @Balflear, strange, but it doesn't work for me. Did you check that argument really remove?

Answer (score 8):

I have come across situations where you want to remove the arguments in a fragment. for example, entering a fragment for the first time maybe you have up to date data, but afterwards on a fragment re-creation you do not want that data, you want to refresh.  you could clear a element in the bundle like this:

```
getArguments().remove("cartDetails");
```

for my case i wrote about, i put that in onCreate of the fragment after getting the initial data.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to change the argument. Instantiate the Fragment again with no argument and replace it with the old one.

If you do not want to recreate the UI and only try to change the music or audio, you can decouple the audio functions from your fragment and put them in a Headless Retained Fragment and you are good to go.

Comment: That's actually what I do, except than when clicking the Home button, and going back to the app, the same instance is called.

Comment: You can use savedInstanceState. You can save the sate onSaveInstanceState. And then onCreate() function of your Fragment, you can check first the savedState and then the arguments. If there is a savedState simply do not look at the Arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Mutating `Bundle` returned by `getArguments()` lies in gray area. You don't know and shouldn't presume how `Fragment` uses that `Bundle` instance.

Ask yourself what happens:

- if they decide to change `getArguments()` to always return different bundle instance (defensive copy)
- or if you change arguments at wrong time