# ReCreate Fragment layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I have actionbar tabs and when a tab is clicked I want to add new button to my fragment.

This is my fragment code where I am adding buttons:

```
    Button btn;
    View myView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int numberOfButtons= getArguments().getInt("someInt",0);
        LinearLayout view =  new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int i = 0;i<numberOfButtons;i++)
        {
            btn = new Button(getActivity());
            view.addView(new Button(getActivity()));
        }
        myView = view;
        return myView;
    }
```

This my MainActivity code where I am sending number of buttons to the fragment:

```
int numberOfButtons=0;
    public static FragmentA newInstance(int someInt) {

        FragmentA myFragment = new FragmentA();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar  actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab"+i).setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                    String tabText = (String)tab.getText();
                    String asd = (String)(tabText.substring(3,tabText.length()));
                    numberOfButtons = Integer.parseInt(asd);
                    FragmentA fragmentA = newInstance(numberOfButtons);
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(R.id.mainLayout,fragmentA,"fragA");
                    transaction.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                }
            });
            actionBar.addTab(tab);
        }
    }
```

This code adds buttons but there is a problem here. When Tab1 is clicked, one button is added to the fragment. When Tab2 is clicked, two buttons are added to the fragment but the first button that added by Tab1 is not removed. One of the new buttons is placed over it.

Is there any way to reset the fragment layout or remove old items of fragment before adding new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems like you're just adding the fragments' instances on top of each other.
The button added by Tab1 is not removed because Tab1 is still there in the background...

Try using the `transaction.remove()` method to remove the previous fragment before calling `transaction.add()` to add a new one...

There's also the `transaction.replace()` method that does both operations at the same time. Perhaps it's also worth a try.

Comment: I have tried transaction.remove() but it did not worked. `transaction.replace()` is worked but you said "it does not always work" :/ What is that mean?

Comment: I stand corrected, I said it doesn't always work because of this guy's post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250580/fragment-already-added-illegalstateexception
But after reading it again - it turns out he was trying to add fragments that have already been added, instead of creating a new instance of the fragment he's adding (like you're doing, which is the right way). I edited my answer :)

Comment: There is one more problem here. While using `transaction.Replace()`,rotating the screen crashes the application. :/

Comment: crashes the application? with what exception? 
the LogCat usually helps a lot in these situations. you can see what line of code made the app crashed, the reason for the crash (the exception type), etc.... 
try posting a separate question, or looking for a similar one here... there's a good chance this has happened to someone before.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found a solution for it but it causes a new problem :) I am keeping search :) Thank you again.