# Android attching fragment inside activity view get Fragment already added Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

in my activity i have simple `FrameLayout` widget and i'm trying to attach simple fragment to that by `replace` and using some fragment into nested fragment but i get `Fragment already added` error when i try to add some fragment in nested fragment, for example this is my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CarouselFragment carouselFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            initScreen();

        } else {
            carouselFragment = (CarouselFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
        }

        ...
    }

    private void initScreen() {
        carouselFragment = new CarouselFragment();

        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, carouselFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

and nested fragment is `CarouselFragment` class :

in this fragment i'm trying to set some other fragment to adapter to use them

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carousel, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    context = getContext();
    viewPager = (ViewPagerCustomDuration) view.findViewById(R.id.vp_pages);

    adapter = new CarouselViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentA());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentB());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.setPageMargin(50);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(4);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```

and then this is my adapter:

```
public class CarouselViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CarouselViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        mFragmentList.add(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        mFragmentList.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Problem is this lines of codes:

```
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentA());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentB());
```

Comment: Check the soln. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250580/fragment-already-added-illegalstateexception) Not exactly your issue but may be u can figure out what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a `FragmentTransaction`.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);  
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Try using tutorial :-http://sapandiwakar.in/replacing-fragments/

Have a look at this:- [Replacing a fragment with another fragment inside activity group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250580/fragment-already-added-illegalstateexception this may help you.

Comment: I tested this solution already, but when i use that my main fragment as `CarouselFragment` dont call and don't run